The issue of having multiple roles on the client side in my Blazor WebAssembly project
<AuthorizeView Roles="@RulesAndRoles.Rules.FirstOrDefault(xd=> xd.Id ==1).Roles.ToString()">
<IconNavLink Href="Management" Icon="fa-star">
@localizer["Management"]
</IconNavLink>
</AuthorizeView>
<AuthorizeView Roles="@RulesAndRoles.Rules.FirstOrDefault(xd=> xd.Id == 2).Roles.ToString()">
<IconNavLink Href="Entity" Icon="fa-star">
@localizer["Entity"]
</IconNavLink>
</AuthorizeView>

The role claims of my JWT token are structured as follows.
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role": [
"Administrator",
"User"
],
I am fetching and populating the necessary roles from my static class RulesAndRoles that I pull from the database, and there is no issue with the system. However, things have changed, and now each user can have multiple roles.
In the above code, @RulesAndRoles.Rules.FirstOrDefault(xd => xd.Id == 1).Roles.ToString() returns a value like "Administrator,Manager". If a user has only "Administrator" or only "Manager" as their role, everything works fine, but if they have both roles at the same time, no AuthorizeView works properly.
How can I solve this issue?
Thank you in advance!
<AuthorizeView Roles="Administrator">
<Authorized>
<p>test admin</p>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
<AuthorizeView Roles="User">
<Authorized>
<p>test user</p>
</Authorized>
<NotAuthorized>
<p>xd</p>
</NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
</NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


I tried this, it works, but it's not very clean. In more complex areas, it makes things even more complicated.

You need to split that into separate claims this is done in different ways depending on the version of blazor and how you are retrieving it, either via middleware or the PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider

You could seperate the jwt role in AuthenticationStateProvider like following:
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        var tokenResult = await _tokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
        if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var accessToken))
        {
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwtToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(accessToken.Value);

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(jwtToken.Claims, "Bearer");

            // Extract and normalize role claims
            var roleClaims = jwtToken.Claims
                .Where(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role")
                .SelectMany(c => c.Value.Split(','))
                .Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Trim()));

            identity.AddClaims(roleClaims);

            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            return new AuthenticationState(user);
        }

        return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
    }
}


Thank you so much, your response was helpful. I had previously split the role claims in the login controller, but it turns out that JWT combines them. Splitting them in the auth provider worked.
Thank you again for taking the time to assist me.

@YusufKıdır Could you help to follow the instruction https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers , thx!
